# How to use gradle feature variant dependecies in tests?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I am migrating a Maven library project to Gradle. The original project also has optional dependencies. I use the [java-library plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) but moving the formerly optional dependencies to implementation results in runtime dependencies instead of compile. So I tried the gradle [feature variants](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/feature_variants.html) which results in the right dependencies in the `pom.xml`. But doing so results is failing test compile as the dependencies of the feature variant are missing on the test compile classpath!

Here is my current setup in `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

java {
  registerFeature('oSupport') {
    usingSourceSet(sourceSets.main)
  }
}

dependencies {
  api 'my.compile:dep-a:1.0.0'
  implementation 'my.runtime:dep-i:1.0.0'
  oSupportApi 'my.optional:dep-o:1.0.0'
}
```

Let's assume there is a class `O` available from `my.optional:dep-o`. If I import `O` in any class in `src/main/java` it works perfectly. Also the dependencies are exported right to Maven (using `gradle generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication`, see the dependencies from the generated `pom.xml` below). But any test in `src/test/java` using class `O` will not compile (`import my.optional.O;` creates  `error: package my.optional does not exist`)

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>my.compile</groupId>
      <artifactId>dep-a</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>my.rintime</groupId>
      <artifactId>dep-r</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>my.optional</groupId>
      <artifactId>dep-0</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

How to solve this? I know I could have used the [nebula.optional-base](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-extra-configurations-plugin) plugin instead of the buildin Gradle feature variant but I would prefer the new gradle builtin support for optional dependencies instead.

PS: I use Java 8 and Gradle 5.6.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug when the feature source set uses the main source set. Can you report on https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues?

In the meantime, this should fix it:

```
configurations {
    testCompileClasspath.extendsFrom(oSupportApi)
    testRuntimeClasspath.extendsFrom(oSupportApi)
    testRuntimeClasspath.extendsFrom(oSupportImplementation)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, at least it works and I can go on, created a bug ticket https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/10778

Answer (score 1):

Really weird, I agree with @melix this seems to be a Gradle [bug](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/10778).

The following will fix it but should not be needed, imho:

```
dependencies {
  api 'my.compile:dep-a:1.0.0'
  implementation 'my.runtime:dep-i:1.0.0'
  oSupportApi 'my.optional:dep-o:1.0.0'
  testImplementation(project(":${project.name}")) {
    capabilities {
      requireCapability("${project.group}:${project.name}-o-support")
    }
  }
}
```

For this simplified setup with only one feature dependency could be replaced by `testImplementation 'my.optional:dep-o:1.0.0'` but for a general larger dependency list this approch avoids repetition of the dependencies as the `extendsFrom` solution of @melix.